# Is there a command that picks random command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make Jarvis like Iron Man,
but the problem is how can I make Jarvis play random between two wav files.
So when I say the hotword ... Jarvis should answer different between this two audio wav files.
Any help?

Code:

```
jv_play voice/YES_1.wav || jv_play voice/YES_2.wav
```

Didn't work with `||`

Answer (score 2):

First place the filenames into an array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sounds=(
  voice/YES_1.wav
  voice/YES_2.wav
)
```

Then use Bash's special `$RANDOM` to select either one of the sounds:

```sh
# Generate a random number the size of the array
random_index=$((RANDOM%${#sounds[@]}))

jv_play "${sounds[random_index]}"
```